# The function set fails to update a non existant path under an existing key

Tags: javascript, node.js

See online playground link: https://repl.it/repls/ChocolateHummingMacroinstruction

I have a function that sets a deep nested property:

```
const rePropName = /[^.[\]]+|\[(?:(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(["'])((?:(?!\2)[^\\]|\\.)*?)\2)\]|(?=(?:\.|\[\])(?:\.|\[\]|$))/g;
const reIsUint = /^(?:0|[1-9]\d*)$/;


function isIndex(value, length = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
  const isNumberLike = (value) => typeof value == 'number' || (typeof value != 'symbol' && reIsUint.test(value));

  return isNumberLike(value) && (value > -1 && value % 1 == 0 && value < length);
}


function stringToPath (string) {
      const result = [];
      if (string.charCodeAt(0) === 46 /* . */) {
        result.push('');
      }

      string.replace(rePropName, function(match, number, quote, subString) {
        result.push(quote ? subString.replace(reEscapeChar, '$1') : (number || match));
      });
      return result;
}


function set(object, path, value) {
  path = stringToPath(path);

  const length = path.length;
  const lastIndex = length - 1;

  let index = -1;
  let nested = object;


  while (nested && ++index < length) {
    const key = path[index];
    let newValue = value;

    if (index !== lastIndex) {
      const objValue = nested[key];
      if (value != null && typeof value == 'object') {
        newValue =  objValue;

      } else if (isIndex(path[index + 1])) {
        newValue = [];
      } else {
        newValue = {};
      }
    }

        const isNotToBeUpdated = (object, key, value) => object.hasOwnProperty(key) && 
        object[key] === value ||
          (value === undefined && !(key in object));

    if (!isNotToBeUpdated(nested, key, newValue)) {
       nested[key] = newValue;
    }
    nested = nested[key];

  }

  return object;
}
```

Given that I have an object that looks like this:

```
const obj = {
  the: {
    dog: {
     and: {
       fox: 123
     }
   }
  }
};

set(obj, 'the.war.of.wolf', 456);
```

It clobbers the existing value of the key and replaces it with the new value:

```
{
  the: {
    war: {
      of: {
        wolf: 456
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Instead, I would like for it to update the nested property without destroying the existing value:

```
{
  the: {
    dog: {
      and: {
        fox: 123
      }
    },
    war: {
      of: {
        wolf: 456
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you have a typo in your code. I'd not provide an answer, though. You should run through a debugger and found it out yourself. (or not so recommended `console.log`)

Comment: plus you should create a [mcve] and remove unused code like `isIndex`